# Indenting lines in each paragraph except the first one using global command

Tags: regular-expression, global-command

I want to indent lines in each paragraph except the first one.

By paragraph, I mean a group of lines that are separated from other groups of lines by at least one blank line.

For example, here we have three paragraphs:

```
paragraph1
line1.1

paragraph2
line2.1
line2.2

paragraph3
```

I want to indent all the lines except the first one in each paragraph. To do this, I use the following command:

```
g/^\w\+/+1,/^\s*$/>
```

The problem is that this command indents every line progressively. The result is as here:

```
paragraph1
    line1.1

paragraph2
    line2.1
        line2.2

paragraph3
```

`line2.2` is indented twice. I guess this occurs because global command matches all lines first with the regex `^\w\+`, then it applies the command `+1,/^\s*$/>`.

How can I produce the following output?

```
paragraph1
    line1.1

paragraph2
    line2.1
    line2.2

paragraph3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind the error message (of the the `+1` going past the last line), just doing

```
:g/^\w/ +>
```

works. Since the pattern for `:global` matches all the lines below `paragraph2` anyway, there is no need to give range to `:>` at all (besides the `+1` to skip the first).